# Strange border issue with Firefox

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to create triangle style shape with CSS, but there a dark line appears on the border as you can see below. It appears in Firefox only, not in the Chrome or IE.

[image]

What is causing this and how this can be fixed?

Here's my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div{
    margin: 20px;

}
h1{
    background: yellow;
    padding: 30px;  
    position: relative;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;  
}

h1:before{
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    content: "";
    border: 20px solid yellow;
    border-width: 0px 50px 80px 0px;
    border-color: transparent transparent yellow transparent;
}
```

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/TrQEH/

Comment: What version of Firefox you are using? I can't see no problems on Aurora 21.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try changing:

```
border-color: transparent transparent yellow transparent;
```

to

```
border-color: transparent #FFF yellow transparent;
```

Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TrQEH/1/)

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that I can not use any color there because the background is not white, it has some image. Do you think there could be any alternative solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare that fuzzy border side as `border-style:inset` and it clears it up in firefox. simply change your styles from:

```
border: 20px solid yellow;  
border-width: 0px 50px 80px 0px;  
border-color: transparent transparent yellow transparent;</code>
```

to

```
border-style:solid inset solid solid;  
border-width: 0px 50px 80px 0px;  
border-color: transparent transparent yellow transparent;
```

works for me in ff19 and chrome Version 26.0.1410.12 dev-m on windows 7

Answer (score 0):

try: border-style: solid dotted